# Python - How to match contents of one text file in another text file and output the result

Tags: python

I have two files - one contains a load of Syslog entries for different network devices (syslog.txt).  The other contains the hostname and IP's of the network devices (hosts.txt).

I want to be able to write a code that outputs any Syslog entries that are from network devices contained in the hosts.txt file.

NB: The hosts.txt file just contains a hostname and IP.  The Syslog entry will contain the hostname/IP + other wording.  I need the whole line outputted from the Syslog file.

Hope that makes sense!

Thank you.

Comment: Hi, provide us a sample of each file so we can help you.

Comment: Example from syslog.txt is:
Sep  4 00:00:03 10.10.10.10 : 2020 Sep  4 00:00:03.689 BST: %ETHPORT-5-IF_UP: Interface Ethernet1/1 is up in mode access

Example from hosts.txt (in this eg cisco is the hostname followed by IP:
cisco 10.10.10.10

Comment: So basically - the hosts.txt contains a hostname followed by IP.  And it can contain any number of hostnames/IP's - currently it has about 50.

The Syslog.txt file contains syslogs from 100's of devices but I'm only interested in the ones from the hosts.txt file.  I want the IP or the hostname to match, which is writte/contained in the syslog entry. And then i need the output of the whole entry - such as Interface UP/DOWN etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a basic example to start with :

```py
hosts_filename = 'hosts.txt'
logs_filename = 'syslog.txt'

with open(hosts_filename, 'r') as f:
    hosts = f.readlines()

with open(logs_filename, 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    
    for line in lines:
        for host in hosts:
            if host in line:
                print(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

Dependent on how the syslog is formed you could run a regex over all lines and then output matching lines.